# How to fetch last data in CI using group_by?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 employees each employee have different warning type:

now i want to display in data table for only one entry of each employee according to the last entry.

Comment: use `DESC sort` on auto increment ID

Comment: could you please show us query or table structure.

Answer (score 0):

use max(primary_key) and then group by data using as you did so you get only last entry of every user.

Answer (score 0):

You can store those values into an Array and then use `end()` function to get the last value.

```
<?php
    $values = array("Rice", "Tea", "Coffee", "Drinks");
    echo end($values); 
?>
```